# Incorrect expression evaluation with expr object in Pure Data

Tags: expression, puredata

I'm trying to print string message once the expression is true, right now the output still prints a message though the expression is false.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is no problem with your expression, but the subsequent dataflow. The bang object [bng] converts any input to a bang message. Even though the expression is correct, the output 0 and 1 will both be converted into a bang. the bang is then printed into the console as "text":bang.

Replace the bang GUI with a [select 1] object and you are almost there.

This is a more Pd-like syntax:

[image: Pd-style]

Also: Please read [Is there any reason to use vanilla Pure Data instead of Pd-extended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793956/is-there-any-reason-to-use-vanilla-pure-data-instead-of-pd-extended/14804106#14804106)

Comment: @user3367643 if you want to get help in the future, you might want to consider **accepting** the best (or only) answer that correctly answers your problem. [so] would soon be dead if people don't "give back".